# Custom select box meta field

Tags: metabox

For my custom post type i needed to add the Attribute Meta box, but i wanted to add an extra field to it.

So here i have copied the Page Attribute meta box code and added my select options, but i need help rewriting the 'Module Type' select box so it functions properly when saving the page.

```
 function page_attributes_meta_box2($post) {
      $post_type_object = get_post_type_object($post->post_type);
       if ( $post_type_object->hierarchical ) {
           $pages = wp_dropdown_pages(array('post_type' => $post->post_type, 'exclude_tree' => $post->ID, 'selected' => $post->post_parent, 'name' => 'parent_id', 'show_option_none' => __('(no parent)'), 'sort_column'=> 'menu_order, post_title', 'echo' => 0));
           if ( ! empty($pages) ) {
   ?>
  <p><strong><?php _e('Parent') ?></strong></p>
   <label class="screen-reader-text" for="parent_id"><?php _e('Parent') ?></label>
   <?php echo $pages; ?>
   <?php
           } // end empty pages check
       } // end hierarchical check.
       ?>
   <p><strong><?php _e('Order') ?></strong></p>
   <p><label class="screen-reader-text" for="menu_order"><?php _e('Order') ?></label><input name="menu_order" type="text" size="4" id="menu_order" value="<?php echo esc_attr($post->menu_order) ?>" /></p>
   <p><?php if ( 'page' == $post->post_type ) _e( 'Need help? Use the Help tab in the upper right of your screen.' ); ?></p>

   <p><strong><?php _e('Module Type') ?></strong></p>
   <label class="screen-reader-text" for="_cnote_module_page_type"><?php _e('Module Type') ?></label>
   <select id="_cnote_module_page_type" name="_cnote_module_page_type">
        <option value="default">Default</option>
        <option value="parent">Parent</option>
        <option value="chat">Chat</option>
   </select>
   <?php
   }

add_action('add_meta_boxes','add_post_template_metaboxr');
function add_post_template_metaboxr() {
    add_meta_box('postparentdiv', __('Post Template'), 'page_attributes_meta_box2', 'module', 'side', 'high');
}
```

**note that i have not renamed everything yet, theres a lot of copy and pasting in here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To save post meta fields from custom meta boxes you need to hook into `save_post` with something like this:

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'myplugin_save_postdata' );
```

There is some full example code on adding meta boxes on the codex [Function Reference/add meta box](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box)